# Sharing Variables in Java Across Classes (Where Persistance and Concurrency Do Not Matter)

Tags: java, class, variables, sharing

I need to share a large number of variables amongst many classes.  So far, I've been passing a map as a parameter between these classes, but this is becoming tedious.  The only other ways I can think of doing this are beans, which would be overkill, because I do not need persistence, a database, which would also be overkill for the same reason, and the below two ways.  (Please note that concurrency is not an issue for this project.)  Between the Singleton and Interface methods, which do you suggest and why?  Do you know of another way?  I imagine there are much better ways of doing what I'm attempting.  My main requirements are reliability and efficiency.  In simple tests, both of the below methods meet my requirements, but I don't know how well they might scale.  Thanks much.

Method 1 (Singleton):

```
package development;

import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Param {

  private Map<Object, Object> params = new TreeMap<Object, Object>();
  private final static Param param = new Param();

  private Param() { System.out.println("<instantiated params>"); };

  public static Param getInstance() {
    return param;
  }

  public void addParam(Object k, Object v) {
    params.put(k,  v);
  }

  public void removeParam(Object k) {
    params.remove(k);
  }

  public Object getParam(Object k) {
    return params.get(k);
  }

  public void printParams() {
    for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> kv : params.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println(kv.getKey() + "->" + kv.getValue());
    }
  }

}


package development;

public class Tester {

  public void doTest() {
    Param.getInstance().addParam("Key 1", "Value 1");
    Param.getInstance().addParam("Key 2", "Value 2");
    Param.getInstance().addParam("Key 3", "Value 3");
    new C1().addAParam();
    new C2().addAParam();
    new C3().addAParam();
    Param.getInstance().printParams();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Tester().doTest();
  }

  private class C1 {
    public void addAParam() {
      Param.getInstance().addParam("Key 4", "Value 4");
    }  
  }

  private class C2 {
    public void addAParam() {
      Param.getInstance().addParam("Key 5", "Value 5");
    }  
  }

  private class C3 {
    public void addAParam() {
      Param.getInstance().addParam("Key 6", "Value 6");
    }  
  }

}

Result:
<instantiated params>
Key 1->Value 1
Key 2->Value 2
Key 3->Value 3
Key 4->Value 4
Key 5->Value 5
Key 6->Value 6
```

Method 2 (Interface):

```
package development;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public interface IParam {
  Map<Object, Object> params = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
}


package development;

import java.util.Map;

public class Tester2 {

  public void doTest() {
    IParam.params.put("Key 1", "Value 1");
    IParam.params.put("Key 2", "Value 2");
    IParam.params.put("Key 3", "Value 3");
    new C1().addAParam();
    new C2().addAParam();
    new C3().addAParam();
    for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> kv : IParam.params.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println(kv.getKey() + "->" + kv.getValue());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Tester2().doTest();
  }

  private class C1 {
    public void addAParam() {
      IParam.params.put("Key 4", "Value 4");
    }  
  }

  private class C2 {
    public void addAParam() {
      IParam.params.put("Key 5", "Value 5");
    }  
  }

  private class C3 {
    public void addAParam() {
      IParam.params.put("Key 6", "Value 6");
    }  
  }

}

Result:
Key 1->Value 1
Key 2->Value 2
Key 3->Value 3
Key 4->Value 4
Key 5->Value 5
Key 6->Value 6
```

Comment: I'm wondering what you could be doing that is causing you to encounter this problem. Could you include a short example of what you're doing now for reference?

Comment: This question would only make any sense if all your data were fully unstructured or with structure changing over time. Otherwise what is wrong with defining plain old Java objects (POJO) for your data? Having said that, singleton is an anti-pattern and your interface example is incomprehensible. If everything you have is fully unstructured then just use a map `Map<String, Object>`, if it is structured as to having random set of keys from a predefined set, define an `enum` for the keys of that map instead of String. But really, the purpose is unclear and smells of bad design...

Comment: The main class receives about fifty parameters from the user (only a single user at a time, and only one per day--that is the contract).  These parameters are stored in a map, and the map is then used by a large number of classes.  Right now, I'm passing the map to all of these classes and also to some of their subclasses.  I'd like a better way to expose all of those classes to the user's input parameters.

Comment: Oleg, I don't understand the bad design smell comment.  My needs are these: get user parameters, and then simply expose those parameters to all classes within the project.  Is that a clearer representation of what I'm trying to do?  In my example, these classes are just private classes within the main test program, but in reality, they will always be external classes.

Comment: Oleg, upon reading other articles on this, I understand the code smell comment now.  So you suggest just doing as I'm already doing and passing around the parameters?  Thanks.